# Using wget to acces to a video download link

Tags: linux, bash, wget

I'm new to bash scripting and as I heard of "wget" I decided to write a script to download just the .mp4 file from a streamcloud (or whatever) link.

I use it normally like:

```
wget -q -O - http://somelink.com | grep keyword
```

(I redirect the wget to the standard out)

But the problem I'm having is that I've realized that I'm just getting the source of the page where you have to wait a few seconds until you can click the "go to video" button. So I'm stuck on it now and I don't know how could I access to the source of the page I'm really interested in, where I'd be able to grep the .mp4 link. I heard something of a post request but to be honest I don't know how to use it so much.

Sorry if I look too newbie in shell scripting, it's just that I am.

Thanks a lot. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looking at the source of the page in your browser (or the request your browser sends with the browser development tools) is likely the simplest way to find the url you need. Assuming the site doesn't work hard to prevent you from finding it. You might also have luck looking for tools designed to do this. A number of such tools exist for various websites.

Comment: Yes, I know it. I can actually do it by looking at the source in the page myself, but when I want to write the script I don't know what can I do to avoid the first page where you have to wait.

Comment: My point was you may not be able to get what you want that easily. If they populate the link with javascript you can't get it with wget, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query, you are only asking to write the output of wget to a file. This works more like redirection.

try:

`wget -e --robots=off -r --level=0 -nc --accept mp4 somewebsite.com`

this will work if the files are saved with a .mp4 extension.

--level=0 is an exception. you could try the command without the --level switch.

Comment: What should your query do? It just creates a directory inside another. Anyway the problem that I'm having is that I'm not wgetting from the source I want to. I'm just getting the source from the page where I have to wait until I can acces to the page of the video (where the mp4 link is).You know what I mean?